# How to use maven wrappers in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-wrapper

I have used NetBeans for years, but never with Maven. I am trying to use Maven wrappers to set up a remote repository utilized by the microservices at my new company; is there a way to do so native to NetBeans so that it's applicable to all Maven projects from that point on?

The only project I have with Maven wrappers currently is one I created via spring.starter.io then imported into NetBeans; should I set the variables for the remote repository in that project then copy that .mvn folder to other projects as needed?

Comment: is there a reason for specifically using maven-wrapper? wouldn't a "regular" maven installation with the default global configuration set up  (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` will prevent you having to copy it to each project... As I understand it, the maven wrapper is for situations where you don't want a full maven installation

Comment: Another observation: if you are developing Spring, have you considered an editor that actually will empoweer you? vscode/intelliJ/spring tools suite all have very good spring support, and maven works well with them.

Comment: (1) Netbeans 16 support Maven. you can open some project include `pom.xml` (2)  you can ignore `mvnw`, `mvnw.cmd`, `.mvn` (3) You can use Netbeans create a Maven project, `File` -> `New Project` -> `Choose Project` -> `Java with Maven`

Comment: Using maven wrappers was recommended by my team lead, as was using environmental variables for the remote repository settings